# Does Cypress have OR condition

Tags: cypress

I came across an old website I used to work with and remembered I updated role name (<role="">).

Is there any way to run the cypress test without having to update the old role name?

In other words, something like:

```
 findByRole("A" or "B") //use one or the other, whatever that exists
```

(I know OR command does not exist in Cypress and cannot find a solution from google so I am stuck..)

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `cy.get()` with `,` and it will act as a OR condition something like:

```js
cy.get('[role="A"],[role="B"]').click()
```

Comment: This works great as is, and when I use it as:                                     
cy.get('[role="A"],[role="B"]',{name: /name/i}).should("exist")                              ,but it doesn't work when I do:                                                           
cy.get('[role="A"],[role="B"]',{name: /name/i}).should("not.exist")                                  I'm curious to know what is the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's called a TextMatch.

```js
findByRole(/A|B/)
```

Since "A" and "B" are just representations of the actual role codes, you will need to  careful about special characters. If it's just alphanumeric characters, no problem.

Comment: Thank you so much for the comment. this solved my:  cy.get('[role="A"],[role="B"]',{name: /name/i}).should("not.exist")  problem with: cy.findByRole(/A|B/,{name: /roles filled/i}).should("not.exist")

Comment: Please be aware, you can't use `{name: /name/i}` with `cy.get()` because it's only an option for `cy.findByRole()` command.

Comment: thank you for the command. I don't get why cy.get....should("not.exist") doesn't work, but .should("exist") works

Comment: Not sure I understand, in the question you have old role "A" and new role "B" and want to find either/or.